# name 'BeautifulSoup' is not defined error

Tags: anaconda

I searched some solution for this error code and I realized that this error's meaning requires rechecking in spelling and I retry to install module 'beautifulsoup'.

The error:

> name 'BeautifulSoup' is not defined error

Frankly I don't have any idea for this error I think there is no error in code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
url="http://finance.naver.com/marketindex"
page=urlopen(url)
soup=BeatifulSoup(page,"html.parser")
```

Comment: yes, check your spelling. It says "BeatifulSoup" on the bottom line, you are missing the `u`.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether your installation is not complete or not. To use beautiful soup, you need to install it:

```
$ pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Then you can use as the following

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4
```

**Note:**    You were doing

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

which will not work as it is not correctly formatted.